# Chrome driver failing when using Behave

Tags: selenium, selenium-chromedriver, python-behave

I'm starting to look at Behave to use for BDD, but I've hit a problem. I have a quite few Selenium (Python) tests that I'm already running successfully, but as soon as I use behave I get an error "chromedriver.exe has stopped working".

In my Selenium tests (using pytest and running it from PyCharm), the test looks as follows (which works fine):

```
def test_open_google():
  driver = webdriver.Chrome('C:/temp/chromedriver.exe')
  driver.get('http://www.google.com')
```

I've then created a steps file (as part of the BDD testing), which contains the following:

```
@when('I open Google')
def step_impl(context):
  driver = webdriver.Chrome('C:/temp/chromedriver.exe')
  driver.get('http://www.google.com')
```

From the command line I run "behave" and get the error popup saying "chromedriver.exe has stopped working.

Does anyone know how I can fix this?

Answer (score 0):

It looks like Behave is not compatible with any of the 32 bit webdrivers. I got the same problem when I used the 32 bit IE driver, but it works when I use the 64 bit driver.